# How should we treat anonymous edits that are useful but don't fit the normal rules?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I came across [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/664759) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/665263) later on the same evening. Normally, I would reject it as it is answering the question posed and completely changing the post. But the problem is that it is suggested by an anonymous user, so if I reject it, it will be lost for good — and although I am completely unfamiliar with sockets, the answer-to-an-answer-posed-as-a-question seems well-informed and I would probably upvote it if I was certain of the validity.

In the meantime, I have clicked <kbd>Not Sure</kbd> but I am concerned that we might lose valuable information from anonymous users who are not willing to create an account and post a full answer. This has now been rejected, and it seems a shame as it was approved by another user (who probably understood it better than I did).

What should I do with these in the future?

Comment: I'd post the info as a comment, "an anonymous user says..."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reject the edit as invalid, since it would effectively deface the question. Check if the answer would be redundant with the existing answers (sometimes users don't seem to understand that they need to scroll down to see the existing answers…). If you think the answer might be worth having but aren't sure, post a community wiki answer containing the text of the edit and a footnote like “posted on behalf of [an anonymous user](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/664759)”. If you get informed-looking complaints in comments that this answer is useless, delete it.

Answer (score 5):

I was wondering about this too, as I'm the one who approved it. But later I realized that the point of the suggested edit review system is to check if those edits fit certain criteria.

Even though it seemed to me that it contained good information, it was after all an **Invalid Edit** and I think it should be treated as such.